# Converting An Array to Image

Tags: python, image

I am having an array of `64*64` consists of `0` and `1`. How do i convert this array to image and save it ?

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.fromarray(data , 'RGB') // 
img.save('my.png')
img.show()
```

'Removing RGB is not giving me expected result All 1's array is also giving me black'

The above code is giving me error ,  i can not convert it, how to convert it if i want to lower resolution image i.e `16*16`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image

import random
data = [random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(64 * 64)]

img = Image.new('1', (64, 64))
img.putdata(data)
img.save('my.png')
img.show()
```

Comment: This is not working in my code.

Answer (score 1):

```html
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from random import randint


# create random array
def create_arr(width, height):
    bin_array = np.zeros((width, height), 'uint8')
    for x in xrange(0, width):
        for y in xrange(0, height):
            bin_array[x, y] = randint(0, 1)
    return bin_array

# write array to img
def create_img(width, height, bin_array):
    rgb_array = np.zeros((width, height, 3), 'uint8')
    for x in xrange(0, width):
        for y in xrange(0, height):
            rgb_array[x, y, 0] = bin_array[x, y] * 255 #R
            rgb_array[x, y, 1] = bin_array[x, y] * 255 #G
            rgb_array[x, y, 2] = bin_array[x, y] * 255 #B

    img = Image.fromarray(rgb_array)
    img.save('img.jpeg')

# create array
bin_array = create_arr(64, 64)
# write bin_array to img
create_img(64, 64, bin_array)
```